# Devious pointer expression (int*)arr

Tags: c

I'm learning c and I'm finding difficulties with the expression `(int*)arr` in the line 18. The whole program is

```
int main () {
    char c, arr['z'-'a'], *pChar;
    int i, *pInt, int matr = 74 ;

    for ( c='a'; c<'z'; c++) {
        arr[c-'a'] = c;
        printf("%c ", arr[c-'a']);
    }
    printf("\n");   

    pChar = arr + matr%15;
    for (i=0; i< 5; i++) {
        printf("%c ", *pChar);
        pChar++;
    }
    printf("\n");

    pInt = (int *)arr + matr%2;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        pChar = (char *)pInt;
        printf("%c ", *pChar);
                pInt++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `arr` as `char` type. As *the name of an array can be used as a pointer to its first element* ; `arr` is a pointer to first `char` of array `arr` and is of type `char *`.
`pInt` is of type `int *`, for the expression

```
pInt = (int *)arr + matr%2;
```

a cast is needed to covert `arr` to `int *` type in your program.

Comment: Further reading: [casting; Type Conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion).

Answer (score 0):

In C when the name of an array is used as a value it represents the address of the first element (`&arr[0]`).

In first case (line 11) you have `pChar = &arr[matr%15]` because pChar is a `char*`

In second case (line 18) you have `pInt = (int *) &arr[matr%15]`. You have to cast pointer to char into pointer to int, bacause pInt is a `int*`

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have been telling you that you need to use a cast to convert `arr` to `int*`.

Better: *Don't* convert `arr` to `int*`.

```
char c, arr['z'-'a'], *pChar;
int i, *pInt, int matr = 74 ;
```

This would be clearer if you'd declare each variable on a line of its own:

```
char c;
char arr['z'-'a'];
char *pChar;
int i;
int *pInt;
int matr = 74;
```

You've declared `arr` as an array of `char`. Assuming an ASCII character set, it has 26 characters. You probably wanted it to have 26.

An expression of array type is implicitly converted, in most contexts, to a pointer to its first element. So `arr` usually becomes an expression of type `char*`, equivalent to `&arr[0]`.

Converting that `char*` pointer to `int*` (which does require a cast) gives you a pointer to an `int` that overlays the first `sizeof (int)` elements of the array.

That's a very odd thing to do, and it actually has undefined behavior (`arr` doesn't necessarily have the proper alignment to store `int` objects).

If you want to store `int` objects, declare an array of `int`.

I haven't studied your code enough to understand what it's intended to do, but there's almost certainly a better way to do it.

Comment: But standard allows the casting.

Comment: The standard allows a lot of things whose behavior is undefined. Whatever the OP is trying to do, I seriously doubt this kind of pointer cast is part of any reasonable solution.